# Should [tag:Brain-Flak] apply to other languages?

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently [brain-flak](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brain-flak), according to the usage guidelines, only applies to [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak) language.  However as Brain-Flak has grown in popularity a number of smaller very closely related languages have sprung up.  So far the inventory of Brain-Flak inspired languages is:

- [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak)
- Miniflak
- [Flakcats](https://github.com/Flakheads/Flakcats)
- [Brain-Flueue](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Brain-Flueue)
- [Brain-Flak Classic](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak/tree/9f22727cc08fc7f48be11393ecfe44db331de55a)
- [Fλak](https://github.com/Flakheads/f-ak)

Already questions on [Miniflak](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/105127/fastest-mini-flak-quine) and [Brain-Flak Classic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/79625/write-a-brain-flak-classic-interpreter) have been tagged with [brain-flak](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brain-flak) and in my opinion this makes a lot of sense for these cases.  Should the [brain-flak](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brain-flak) be expanded to encompass related languages which might be too small or infrequently used to warrant their own tags?

Answer (score 4):

**In your specific example? Yes.**

I think there are plenty of reasons that flak-like languages should be tagged with [brain-flak](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brain-flak)

- Miniflak is a direct subset of brain-flak, so you could even get away with pretending the language doesn't exist and calling it a [brain-flak](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brain-flak) [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source) question.
- Brain-flak Classic *is* brain-flak, just less evolved/refined. Classic was the first finished version of brain-flak to be used/published. The current version is the original with the `[...]` and `[]` functions changed [to make it more powerful](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak/issues/5#issuecomment-228446583). As far as I'm concerned, classic is like a *version zero*, and the current is version one. FWIW, the only challenge specific to classic was written before the change. I noticed this a while ago, and edited the title/description to avoid confusing people about what `[]` is supposed to do.
- I highly doubt there will be enough questions specific to a variant of brain-flak to make it worth adding a tag for any variant.

But there's a more general question too. "Should questions about X be tagged with Y, when X is inspired by/a subset of Y?" This is a good question since we have *tons* of language-variants. For example, there is V/Vim, J/Jelly, Python/Pyth, Actually/Seriously, Brachylog/Prolog, etc. Not to mention the 8-trillion brainf*** variants.

**In this more general case? It varies.**

In a lot of cases, it comes down to discretion, but a good general guideline is

> Is X largely backwards compatible with Y, or Y with some gag tacked on? If so, the [y](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/y) tag is a appropriate. Otherwise, it should be untagged or have it's own tag made.

For some more concrete examples:

- If I were to ever make a V specific question, I would most definitely tag it with vim. This is because V is *mostly* backwards compatible. (If I had to guess, I'd say ~90%~ of vim programs could be run in the V interpreter with no problems) Also, I don't think it's worth creating a tag just for V.
- Questions about Ook! or compressedf***, or bitf*** or whatever variant of brainf*** you have should be tagged with [brainfuck](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brainfuck), because in most cases they *are* the same language, with the silly substitution rules tacked on to the end.
- Questions about Pyth or Jelly or Brachylog should definitely *not* be tagged with [python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) or [j](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/j) or [prolog](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prolog) respectively. This is because they have evolved enough to pass the point of being "a variant", and as far as I know, attempting to run J code in the Jelly interpreter or vice-versa would absolutely not work. Same for the other languages. (I don't actually know how to use any of these languages, so someone please correct me if I'm wrong)

I purposefully said "Untagged or have it's own tag made", because this varies too, mostly depending on popularity of the language/number of potential questions to tag it with. I'd say if you can foresee putting the tag on *at least* 3-4 questions, making a new tag should be fine.