# Can we remove some useless tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I recently had a look through the ["new" tags](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=new) and found that most of them apply to 1 or 2 questions, and aren't really necessary. Can we remove these obsolete tags? For reference, the tags I'm referring to are:

- [Circuit golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circuit-golf), which currently applies to 2 questions, one [closed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/159516/make-a-bcdto7seg-chip) and the [other](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/159522/make-a-128-64-divider) is due to be cleaned up in the next few days:

  > The system will automatically delete unlocked, unanswered questions that have negative score that are at least 30 days old <sub>[Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/355458)</sub>
- [Computability Theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computability-theory), with a single question with that tag. If this one isn't removed, it would greatly benefit a tag description
- [Yabasic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yabasic), which seems as though it could be merged with the existing, and used, [basic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/basic) tag.

  - [Ubasic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ubasic) and [Visual Basic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual-basic) are also very similar, with 1 and 2 questions respectively
- [Mapping](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mapping), where [one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/156918/rgb-to-xterm-color-converter) of the tagged questions doesn't appear to apply, and the [other](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/158044/66833) seems to be covered by [image-processing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing)

Thoughts on removing or keeping these tags?

---

Side note: Remember, users with more than 1,250 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on a given tag can vote on [tag synonyms](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) for that tag, and a few synonyms are *still* pending.

Comment: The two [tag:mapping] questions seem to be about different definitions of the word, one about geographical mapping and the other about computational mapping.

Comment: FWIW a tag which only has one question [will be deleted automatically after 6 months](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/should-we-zap-the-low-occurrence-tags/48418#48418)

Comment: I say, Thin 'em out!

Comment: I voted on the pending tag synonyms. Personally, I don't think the suggestion for [ascii] -> [ascii-art] makes sense.

Answer (score 9):

*Note, all of this is my opinion as a user, not as a moderator*

---

A lot of these tags are certainly useless. But some of them aren't bad tags just because there aren't a lot of questions for them. Here are my thoughts on each tag individually:

- [mathematics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics) <s>Should definitely be a synonym of</s> is actually now a synonym of [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)
- [circuit-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circuit-golf) Seems like a useful tag to me. It's a specialization of [atomic-code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atomic-code-golf), but I can find several questions I think it would be appropriate on:

  - [Build a 4-vertex Connectedness Tester using NAND gates](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/69912/31716)
  - [Build a NAND gate using multiple NAND gates](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/12229/31716)
  - [building circuit for divisibility by 3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/24834/31716)
  - [Build a 2-way universal logic processor using NAND logic gates](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/24983/31716)

  Additionally, it's different than [logic-gates](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic-gates) because not all challenges related to logic gates are necessarily circuit golf challenges. This tag could use a better wiki, but I see no reason to remove it.
- [computability-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computability-theory) This is another one that I think is useful. Granted, I'm not an expert in computability theory, so I don't know if there are many other questions this could be applied to. But as far as I can tell it fits the one question it's on, and there could be other questions with a similar theme to them. IMO, having only one relevant question is a good reason to *not add* a tag, but not a good reason to remove it.
- [whatever-basic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whatever-basic) Absolutely agree with OP. All questions tagged with *something-basic* should have the [basic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/basic) tag added, and the *something-basic* tag removed. I wrote more on that subject [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11537/31716).

  Update: Burninated!
- [mapping](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mapping) Again, absolutely agree. What could this tag even possible be about? Geographical maps? Not worth having, and if it was it should be [geography](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geography) instead. Dictionaries? [data-structures](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-structures) My vote? [Burninate it](https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.215635643.7844/raf,750x1000,075,t,9ec0d5:0d26d5c715.jpg)

  Update: Burninated!

Comment: I'd like to note that *something-basic* should be merged only if it's actually a variant of Basic.  It's the language that matters, not the name (In case you weren't bothered to read the link in the post)

Comment: @NathanMerrill I went back and double checked all of the x-basic tags. They all look like basic dialects to me?

Comment: Oh, they are :)  I'm just clarifying for future readers.

Comment: For the record, VB is nothing like what most people think of just basic.

Comment: TI-Basic is defined to be BASIC-like in Wikipedia, and I don't think they are similar. But there isn't a tag.

Comment: Maybe also remove VBA(Visual Basic for Applications) please?

Comment: Why [tag:smilebasic] survive?